# Calculate in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate in Javascript but having Strange Problems.
It just adds an 1 to my String but it should calculate it. I am converting my Strings to Int with the parseInt() Function and a am calculating like this: `sec = sec + 1;`

```
 var calc= parseInt($(this).find("input[name=calc]").val());
                calc = calc + 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string must not be empty if don't want `NaN`. First check if you get an empty string:

```
var cal = null;

if ( $(this).find("input[name=calc]").val() ) {

    cal = parseInt( $(this).find("input[name=calc]").val(), 10 );
    cal++;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!!sec){ 
    sec = parseInt(sec, 10) + 1;

    alert(sec);
}
```

Or, in your scenario:

```
var fieldvalue = $(this).find("input[name=calc]").val(), calc;

if(!!fieldvalue){
    calc = parseInt(fieldvalue, 10);

    calc += 1;

    alert(calc);
}
```

Comment: What are you putting in the `sec` variable?

Comment: use `alert('...')` or `console.log('...')` to debug the value of `$(this).find("input[name=calc]").val()`.

Comment: sec is empty on the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more code to express. It may just be coming out to 1, because sec is not set as a number

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the + operator is used for addition **and** concatenation of strings.
As javascript is weakly typed, you have to add information about the type. Here are two solutions:

- Substract 0 from the string

  sec = (sec-0) + 1;
- Add unary + operator to the string

  sec = (+sec) + 1;